# how to load multiple images, one by one to ImageView, at a set interval using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am try to do a slideshow when I click on a button, ImageView will show all the pictures/drawable from Integer pics[] one by one at a time continuously with a set interval speed that I will chose from the radiobuttons(3 choices) on the screen.

I try to achieve showing one by one image at a time without AsyncTask, with the following, but it just show the last image and no time delay in between each pictures.

```
for (Integer p:pics)
{
    iv.SetImageResource(p);
    SystemClock.sleep(500);
}
```

the following code is what I have so far, I need help on on the bottom of AsyncTask, how to achieve one by one image at a set interval time

```
public class PhotoAlbum extends Activity
{   
    static final int intSlow = 3000;
    static final int intMed = 1000;
    static final int intFast = 500;

    ImageView iv;
    int interval;
    Integer pics[] = {
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,
        R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,
        R.drawable.img6
    };

    RadioButton rbSlow;
    RadioButton rbMedium;
    RadioButton rbFast;
    Button mAutoButton;

    private int currentImage = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_album);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageResource(pics[currentImage]);

        rbSlow = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioSlow);
        rbMedium = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMedium);
        rbFast = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFast);

        mAutoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAuto);

        mAutoButton.setOnClickListener(AutoButtonChangeImageListener);

    }
    private View.OnClickListener AutoButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            AutoPicsTask.execute();
        }
    };

    private class AutoPicsTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>
    {
        if (rbSlow.isChecked())
        {
            interval = intSlow;
        } else if (rbMedium.isChecked())
        {
            interval = intMed;
        } else
        {
            interval = intFast;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params)
        {
            for (Integer p : pics)
            {
                SystemClock.sleep(interval);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer ...value) {
            iv.setImageResource(value[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I am really new to AsyncTask.

This is an assignment using what we have learn so far. 
We have not learn how to use "handler", timer, runOnUiThread(), creating a thread, void run(), postDelayed(), animate, which I see some of the post suggesting to use to achieve  one image at a time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `thanks in advance.`. Dont say you learned this bad habit in the course.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting image resource in onPostExecute. You must do it every after or before SystemClock.sleep(interval). In doInBackground(), you can not change UI elements but there is of course a solution for it.

Use runInUiThread() method. it takes an runnable object. Set your imageView inside it.

```
for (Integer p : pics){
            SystemClock.sleep(interval);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
                public void run() {
                    iv.setImageResource(p);
                }
            } );
}
```

Comment: thank you.  But we haven't learn how to use  runOnUiThread() method. We're only using what we learn in class so far.

Comment: Are you not ALLOWED to use other things?

Comment: Bad idea to use runInBackground in an AsyncTask as the AsyncTask has publishProgress/onProgressUpdate just for that.

Comment: Yes it has. but I think it does same things on background. Tell me why runOnUiThread is bad programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code as a timer

```
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) { //this will make 5 minute delay

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            // write the code of changing pictures
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            try{

                //write the code when finishing
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: What a nonsence. You see how it is used here. So grab it. And then you have learned again.

Comment: Our teacher just want us to practice using what is taught to us ... the post didn't go to waste. I will now know to use timer in the future if I approach this same problem.